# Basic Event Cancellation

Tags: c#, event-handling

I recently came across the need to allow consumers to prevent further execution of methods and I utilized an event driven system that allows the consumer to specify if the execution should cancel. I've tested it in a multi-threaded environment and everything is working as expected so as a simple solution it works as intended with no issues. However, I can't help but wonder where there are improvements that could be made as I've never dealt with event cancellations before.

### Event Arguments Definition

```
public class CustomEventArgs {
    public bool Cancel { get; set; } = false;
}
```

I'm not sure that a default value for the `Cancel` property is a good idea here.

### Object Definition

```
public class MyCustomObject {
    public void Count(int countTo) {
        if (ShouldCount()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < countTo;)
                Console.WriteLine(++i);
        } else
            Console.WriteLine("Counting process was cancelled by the consumer.");

        Console.WriteLine("The counting process has completed.");
    }
    public event EventHandler<CustomEventArgs> OnStarting;
    private bool ShouldCount()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The counting process is starting.");
        CustomEventArgs args = new CustomEventArgs();
        OnStarting?.Invoke(this, args);
        return !args.Cancel;
    }
}
```

I believe that `return !args.Cancel` is a little confusing to read as negative logic. Perhaps it should be `return args.Cancel` and the method should be renamed to something like `ShouldCancelCounting` and check for `if (!ShouldCancelCounting())` instead of `if (ShouldCount())`?

### Consumption

```
private static bool CancelEvent = false;
private static void RunTest() {
    CancelEvent = false;
    MyCustomObject obj = new MyCustomObject();
    obj.OnStarting += CountStarting;
    obj.Count(100);

    CancelEvent = true;
    MyCustomObject obj = new MyCustomObject();
    obj.OnStarting += CountStarting;
    obj.Count(100);
}
private static void CountStarting(object sender, CustomEventArgs e) {
    e.Cancel = CancelEvent;
}
```

What are some areas that are harder to follow with this implementation? Is there anything confusing about it in any way? Is there any official Microsoft documentation on implementing event cancellations? What are some potential gotchas with my implementation?

Comment: As you are a self-confessed rookie with cancellation, perhaps should rely upon what's already in the .NET Framework rather than rolling your own custom solution.  See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads,

Comment: Does this cide work as intended? Did you test it?

Comment: @RickDavin thank you for the reading material; I'm reading over it now. :)

Comment: @Heslacher this code does in fact work as I intended it to. I tested it with nested multi-threading for added complexity.